# Nav menu will not center

Tags: css, menu, alignment, center

My nav menu will not center. And I can't find the fault in the code. Maybe someone can help me?!

```css
#nav-header {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    margin-top: 80px;
}

#nav-header li.nav-link {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif,"Open Sans", "Helvetica",sans-serif;
    font-size: 28pt;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;

    
}
```

```html
 <ul id="nav-header">
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Game</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Higschore</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Kind regards,

Jelmer

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong text-align. text-align: center; still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to the parent element.

```css
#nav-header {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    margin-top: 80px;
    text-align:center; /* see here */
}

#nav-header li.nav-link {
    display: inline-block; /* preferable to plain inline */
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif,"Open Sans", "Helvetica",sans-serif;
    font-size: 28pt;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;

    
}
```

```html
 <ul id="nav-header">
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Game</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Higschore</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-align: center` to `#nav-header`:

```css
#nav-header {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    margin-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav-header li.nav-link {
    display: inline;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif,"Open Sans", "Helvetica",sans-serif;
    font-size: 28pt;
    text-align: inherit;
    margin: 0 auto;

    
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav-header">
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Game</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Higschore</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First at all you will need to reset the default `padding` of the `ul`, then since you are using `inline` for the `li` elements you can use `text-align` property on the container to center the elements inside:

```
#nav-header {
   padding:0;
   text-align:center;
}
```

---

```css
#nav-header {
  height: 60px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  margin-top: 80px;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center;
}
#nav-header li.nav-link {
  display: inline;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif, "Open Sans", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size: 28pt;
  text-align: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav-header">
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Game</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Higschore</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```